# Controlar el timezone al publicar un tweet con la api de twitter y /statuses/update.json

Tags: php, twitter-api

Estoy usando la clase [TwitterAPIExchange.php](https://github.com/J7mbo/twitter-api-php) para publicar tweets pero al crearlos la api setea en el atributo created_at la hora en GMT global y mi intención es publicarlo a las 09:00 hora española.

Por ejemplo, si publico un tweet ahora (22:01 hora española), el tweet se publica en el momento, pero en la hora aparece 13:01 - 24 ene. 2017

¿Sabéis si puede modificarse este atributo al publicar el tweet o pasarle el timezone?

He intentado cambiar el timezone (el servidor tiene timezone 'America/New York') en el script php antes de publicar el tweet pero no parece funcionar.

¿Alguna idea?

Os dejo el código, aunque tampoco creo que ayude mucho...

```
$tweet = "Este es mi tweet"

/** If url exists, send tweet */
if ($retcode === 200) {

  /** API URL to send tweets */ 
  $url = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";
  $requestMethod = 'POST';

  $postFields = array();
  $postFields['status'] = $tweet; 

  $twitter = new TwitterAPIExchange($settings);

  $json =  $twitter->setPostfields($postFields)
    ->buildOauth($url, $requestMethod)
    ->performRequest();

}
```

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update

Bueno, el problema estaba en la configuración de la cuenta con la que estaba haciendo la autenticación que tenía el time zone incorrecto.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta y añade tu codigo y especifica el error que te esta apareciendo.

Comment: Hola,

Creo que he enconrtado la solución, hay una llamada sobre la api que pertmir configurar ese tipo de parametros.

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/account/settings

Simplemente, sería setear el time_zone a 'Europe/Madrid' y debería funcionar, por si alguien se encuentra con el mismo problema ;)

Comment: Excelente! Responde a tu pregunta para que otros puedan obtener respuesta si tienen el mismo problema